# Problems with regex parsing

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a program using the lynx command on this page "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/movie/box_office.php" and I can't seem to wrap my head around a certain problem.... getting the title by itself. My problem is a title can contain special characters, numbers, and all titles are variable in length. I want to write a regex that could parse the entire page and find lines like this....
(I added spaces between the title and the next number, which  is how many weeks it has been out, to distinguish between title and weeks released)

```
1 -- 30%  The Vow                                           1 $41.2M $41.2M $13.9k 2958
2 -- 53%  Safe House                                        1 $40.2M $40.2M $12.9k 3119
3 -- 42%  Journey 2: The Mysterious Island                  1 $27.3M $27.3M $7.9k 3470
4 -- 57%  Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace (in 3D) 1 $22.5M $22.5M $8.5k 2655
5 1  86%  Chronicle                                         2 $12.1M $40.0M $4.2k 2908
```

the regex I have started out with is:

```
/(\d+)\s(\d+|\-\-)\s(\d+\%)\s
```

If someone can help me figure out how to grab the title successfully that would be much appreciated! Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Was your assignment to parse the page, or to write a regex to parse the page? If it's the former, you should consider using a DOM library instead of a regex.

Comment: Is using a regular expression to do this required? Since the data is already justified, why not just snip out the appropriate column and then apply a trim function?

Comment: I agree with both of you completely but the assignment is to use the lynx command and parse all the information =/

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your question shows a text representation of the page, but that text representation doesn't exist anywhere. The actual page is HTML. And in the HTML, the data is wrapped in a table and the solution is simple — extract the fourth column of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture all the things!!

```
^(\d+)\s+(\d+|\-\-)\s+(\d+\%)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+(\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+(\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+(\d+)$
```

Explained:

```
^                            <- Start of the line
    (\d+)\s+                 <- Numbers (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\d+|\-\-)\s+            <- Numbers [or "--"] (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\d+\%)\s+               <- Numbers [with '%'] (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (.*)\s+                  <- Anything you can match [don't be greedy] (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\d+)\s+                 <- Numbers (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+  <- "$" and Numbers [with floating point] and "M or k" (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+  <- "$" and Numbers [with floating point] and "M or k" (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\$\d+(?:.\d+)?[Mk])\s+  <- "$" and Numbers [with floating point] and "M or k" (captured) followed by as many spaces as you want
    (\d+)                    <- Numbers (captured)
$                            <- End of the line
```

---

So to be serious this is what I've done, I cheated a bit and captured everything (as I think you'll do in the end) to get a lookahead for the title capture.

In a non-greedy regex `(.*)` [or `(.*?)` if you want to force the "ungreedyness"] will capture the least possible characters, and the end of the regex tries to capture everything else.

Your regex ends up capturing only the title (the only thing left).

What you can do is using an actual lookahead and make assertions.

---

**Resources:**

- [regular-expressions.info - Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [regexr.com - This regex tested](http://regexr.com?3016k)

Comment: That definitely worked on grabbing all things in the line! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I did most of the work (assignment) because I don't think there's an easy way to explain the regex without giving the regex itself. But I hope that you read the explanation and that you'll read the regular-expressions.info link (it's really interesting anyway).

Comment: Grabbing this is only a little part of the assignment. There is more regex for me to write I was just having trouble on figuring out how to get the entire title. This is only my second regex assignment so still trying to figure it all out.